# Валидатор телефонного номера на php (регулярка)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно написать валидатор мобильных номеров, где в начале будет ЛИБО +7 ЛИБО 8, а после них 10 любых цифр, возможно с пробелами (в т.ч. в начале , тире и круглыми скобками.
Я в качестве этого самого "либо" поставил символ | но чё-т не работает, подскажите где косяк плиз

```
$inputData = '+70123456789'; // номер телефона
$regexp = '/^[+]7|8[0-9()-]{10}$\\s/'; 

if (preg_match($regexp, $inputData)) { 
echo "Номер отображается корректно \n"; 
} else { 
echo "Ошибка"; 
}
```

Comment: Напишите варианты исходной строки с пробелами, скобками и тире -- я подкорректирую свой ответ.

Comment: // Правильные: 
$correctNumbers = [ 
  '84951234567',  '+74951234567', '8-495-1-234-567', 
  ' 8 (8122) 56-56-56', '8-911-1234567', '8 (911) 12 345 67', 
  '8-911 12 345 67', '8 (911) - 123 - 45 - 67', '+ 7 999 123 4567', 
  '8 ( 999 ) 1234567', '8 999 123 4567'
];

// Неправильные: 
$incorrectNumbers = [
  '02', '84951234567 позвать люсю', '849512345', '849512345678', 
  '8 (409) 123-123-123', '7900123467', '8888-8888-88',
  '84951a234567', '8495123456a', 
  '+1 234 5678901', /* неверный код страны */
  '+8 234 5678901', /* либо 8 либо +7 */
  '7 234 5678901' /* нет + */
];

Comment: Ок, я завтра напишу шаблоны и отредактирую свой ответ.

Comment: Может, `preg_match('~\A\D*(?:\+7|8)(?:\D*\d){10}\D*\z~', $inputData)`? `\D` можно заменить на что-то более конкретное, например `[\s()-]`, а `*` на `?` если спец. символы разрешены только 1 раз.

Answer (score 1):

Для поиска строки `'+70123456789'` или `'80123456789'` будет достаточно такого шаблона `'~^(?:\+7|8)\d{10}$~'`. А вот на счёт пробелов, тире и круглых скобок - необходимо точно знать все их варианты вхождения в исходную строку.

---

```
// Корректные номера
$correctNumbers = [
    '84951234567',
    '+74951234567',
    '8-495-1-234-567',
    ' 8 (8122) 56-56-56',
    '8-911-1234567',
    '8 (911) 12 345 67',
    '8-911 12 345 67',
    '8 (911) - 123 - 45 - 67',
    '+ 7 999 123 4567',
    '8 ( 999 ) 1234567',
    '8 999 123 4567' 
];

$arr = array_filter($correctNumbers, function($str){
    $patt = '~' .
        '^(?:\+7|8)\d{10}$|' .
        '^8[\s-]\d{3}-\d(?:-\d{3})+$|' .
        '^\s?8\s?\(\d{4}\)\s?\d{2}(?:-\d{2}){2}$|' .
        '^8-\d{3}-\d{7}$|' .
        '^8\s?\(\d{3}\)\s?\d{2}\s?\d{3}\s?\d{2}$|' .
        '^8-\d{3}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{3}\s?\d{2}$|' .
        '^8\s?\(\d{3}\)\s?-\s?\d{3}(?:\s?-\s?\d{2}){2}$|' .
        '^\+\s?7(?:\s?\d{3}){2}\s?\d{4}$|' .
        '^8\s?\(\s?\d{3}\s?\)\s?\d{7}$|' .
        '^8(?:\s?\d{3}){2}\s?\d{4}$' .
    '~';
    return preg_match($patt, $str);
});

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: а если вначале удалить все пробелы тире и скобки из строки а потом проверять полученный номер?

Comment: @СтасКалиновский обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// by Pirajog

$regexp = '/^\s?(\+\s?7|8)([- ()]*\d){10}$/';

// Правильные
$correctNumbers = [ 
  '84951234567',  '+74951234567', '8-495-1-234-567', 
  ' 8 (8122) 56-56-56', '8-911-1234567', '8 (911) 12 345 67', 
  '8-911 12 345 67', '8 (911) - 123 - 45 - 67', '+ 7 999 123 4567', 
  '8 ( 999 ) 1234567', '8 999 123 4567'
];

// Неправильные: 
$incorrectNumbers = [
  '02', '84951234567 позвать люсю', '849512345', '849512345678', 
  '8 (409) 123-123-123', '7900123467', '5005005001', '8888-8888-88',
  '84951a234567', '8495123456a', '+1 234 5678901', '+8 234 5678901',
  '7 234 5678901'
];


// Проверяем правильные номера
foreach ($correctNumbers as $key)
{
    if (preg_match($regexp, $key))
    {
        echo $key."\n";
    }
}
```